# How to insert the value of a variable in a char*

Tags: c++, native

I have mastered C# and I decided to start on C++ to work on a few private things. Anyways I wanna know how to do this (C#) in C++.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
 say("[" + i + "] idk");
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, also if it helps I am writing in Native C++.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `stringstream`s,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ostringstream os;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        os << "[" << i << "] idk";
        cout << os.str() << endl; // replace by `say(...)` in your code
        os.str(""); // clear the stream for the next iteration
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

By itself, `"["` is a C-style string constant.  It's immutable and no overloaded `+` operator is defined for it.  But if you use `std::string`, you'll get something resembling C# strings.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    say(std::string("[") + "] idk");
```

That only works for appending other strings.  If you want to append something that isn't a string, you need to convert it first.  The easiest way is to use std::ostringstream:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    std::ostringstream ostr;
    ostr << "[" << i << "] idk";
    say(ostr.str());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is suggested in the comment by chris.

```
#include <string>
for (int i{0}; i != 16; ++i) {
    say("[" + std::to_string(i) + "] idk");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
 say("[" + i + "] idk");
```

First of all, try to change your `for`-loop style to use pre-increment rather than post-increment. It doesn't make a difference for `int` but will be consistent with other cases where it can make a difference.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
```

Now one should explain why exactly the addition statement fails. Beware, for this going to be **much** more complicated than the actual solution, but is IMO important to understand.

You probably get an error message saying something like `invalid operands of types const char* and const char [6]`. This is because in C++, basic string handling is inherited from C, which has no string class but deals with arrays of characters, the end of the string being defined by convention with an "invisible" so-called null character alias `'\0'` as the last element of the array.

In particular,

- `"["` is considered an unmodifiable array of 2 characters, including
  the terminating null character. In other words, it is a literal of
  type `char const [2]`, which can also be written as `const char[2]`.
- `"] idk"` is considered an unmodifiable array of 6 characters, again
  including the terminating null character. It is a literal of type
  `char const [6]` or `const char[6]`.

Now let's disect the `"[" + i + "] idk"` expression.

The first addition is that of `"["` and `i`. It adds an `int` to a `const char[2]`. This happens to be a legal operation in C++, the result being a *pointer* to an unmodifiable character, a `char const *` (which can also be written as `const char *`), i.e. an address of a character in memory. You practically take the address of the first element of the array and advance from there `i` times. This, of course, is complete nonsense here and already leads to undefined results because you are accessing a memory region which you must not try to access.

Nonetheless, the compiler lets you do it, and so you are left with a `const char *` as the result of the first addition.

The second addition is then that of `"[" + i` and `"] idk"`. It attempts to add a `const char[6]` to a `const char*`. And finally, this is where the compiler complains, because adding an array to an address doesn't make sense at all.

As you can see, fiddling with arrays and pointers is not nice. Fortunately, C++ has a real string class. It's called `std::string` and has the expected behaviour for `+` additions. You have to turn the middle operand into a `std::string` and you'll be fine. In order to turn the `int` into a `std::string`, use `std::to_string` if you use C++11, or else `std::ostringstream`.

```
"[" + std::to_string(i) + "] idk"
```

This will work, because the first addition will be one of `const char[2]` and `std::string`, which has the expected string-concatenation behaviour, resulting in a new `std::string`, and the second addition will be that of the new `std::string` and `const char[6]`, also with the expected behaviour.

In fact, with `std::string`, all the character-array handling appears to be automated, and you will almost never have to care about the C legacy anymore.